# Copy const to char*

Tags: c++

I have

```
       std::ostringstream out;
       out << name << len << data;
       std::string const value = out.str();
```

I want to copy this const value to a char*

```
        char* buff; 
        size_t length = strlen(value); 
        buff = new char[(strlen(value))+ 1]; 
        memcpy(nm, value , length + 1);
```

but it is still giving me error? Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `value.size()` instead of `strlen(value)`.

```
 char* buff; 
 size_t length = value.size();
 buff = new char[length+1]; 
 memcpy(buff, value.c_str() , length + 1); 
       //^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^ also note this
```

Or you can copy in this as well:

```
 std::string copy = value;
 const char * buff = copy.c_str();
```

But note that `buff`  will exist as long as the variable `copy` exists. In other words, the lifetime of `buff` is tied with the lifetime of the variable `copy`, and you don't need to write `delete buff` in this case.

Comment: For the above code I get error: error: cannot convert 'const std::string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)' For further information in my code: char name = 'V'; int len = 1; char data[5];

Comment: @Kiran: I assume you are describing the error you get in *your* code, not Nawaz's code. You should edit your question to include the error message, not put it in a comment.

Comment: Careful with the second version there. Any modification of copy will invalidate buff.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using memcpy anyway? There is strcpy for the purpose of copying strings:

```
char *c = new char[value.length() + 1];
strcpy(c, value.c_str());
```

Comment: You must use `new char[value.length() + 1]` to account for the terminating nul character.

Comment: I would use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` to combat buffer overflow.